# Sharing Realm instance between React Native and Android

Tags: realm, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project that uses Realm for React Native.
It works without problems but now, I am faced with a problem of writing Android Service that would use the same Realm instance. Is it possible and how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can communicate from Java to React Native through [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content) and do your Realm-related code in Javascript as you normally would.

Otherwise, [Realm for Android's multi-process support for non-encrypted Realms will arrive in Realm-Java 2.0.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1091#issuecomment-244039670) (and that part is actually *in* with the snapshot), which will most definitely support this use-case; when the core version of Realm-React-Native (currently 1.5.0) and Realm-Java (previously 1.5.1, now 2.0.0-rc4) will be the same (2.0.0).

So not yet, but actually quite soon. I'd estimate a month or two at most from the time of writing.

---

EDIT: According to https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/984#issuecomment-297716769 the only way to get the same core and sync and object-store versions reliably for your app is if you build Realm-JS and Realm-Java from scratch and use them in your application like that.

Comment: You will also need to make sure the core version used by both bindings is the same - you can ensure this by choosing binding versions which have this aligned, or by building each binding yourself from source.

Comment: Yeah, I did specify that the cores must be the same (better to hear it from an official of course :P), although unfortunately they never actually used exactly the same versions so far - probably with the Java side's ObjectStore integration that will change if it's aligned right (and Java side wouldn't have liked the "multi-process" access anyways, because React Native's writes wouldn't have triggered a refresh on the Java side) - if they both get released with a Core 2.0.0, then they'll be connectable

Comment: Hey! have you managed to accesd the same Realm instance from Javascript land and Java land? a code example would great... we are facing the same problem here.