# Using shared Realm db between Android native code and React Native code within the same Android app

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have an android app which has some components written in java code and some components in javascript using React Native. I create a Realm DB in my app which needs to be be accessed (both Read/Write) from both type of components.

I have already gone through the following links

[Sharing Realm instance between React Native and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489065/sharing-realm-instance-between-react-native-and-android)

[Realm React-Native: Access same realm from JS(react native code) and android(java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634172/realm-react-native-access-same-realm-from-jsreact-native-code-and-androidjav)

Both of them says its not possible unless you build both Realm Java and RealmJS from scratch.
To check this, I created one prototype and was successfully able to read the data from realm DB in java code which was inserted in react native code.
The versions of Realm used are

Realm Java 5.0.0

Realm JS 2.3.3

However, I had to add @Required for the property in my java code which is a separate issue

```
@Required
private String name;
```

My main concern is that my prototype just covers the basic scenario. So I wanted to check could there be any problems using realm in this way?

Comment: I've been using Realm Java version 3.7.2 and JS version 1.12.0 out of the box without having to make any changes to Java code. It's not a big app so afraid I can't comment on any problems you might encounter. I've actually been looking to upgrade but had issues changing to the versions you're using. Did you have to use `@Required` in your RealmObject classes to get it to work?

Comment: With the versions which I have used, by default any field in java object was optional and mandatory in java script . So this was throwing exception when running the app. So I had to either add @Required in java or {optional: true} in java script to make them compatible.